# How to model this data?

Tags: bayesian, multilevel-analysis, logit

I have a dataset with the following structure:

```
Choice   Bank Bank_x  Customer Customer_x
  0      UBS     .       1          .
  1      CS      .       1          .
  1      KZ      .       1          .
  0      VA      .       1          .
--------------------------------------
  0      UBS     .       2          .
  0      CS      .       2          .
  1      KZ      .       2          .
  0      VA      .       2          .
```

---

Where choice is whether a customer would open an account in a given bank tomorrow (0 = no, 1 = yes). In the data there are a number of bank and customer specific variables.

My first thought was to use a Hierarchical logit model with bank choices nested within customers, so as to get parameters for each customer. However I am suddenly in doubt about whether this is the right choice, and I would like to hear any thougths from you guys before I settle on an approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds reasonable to me.  I guess the customer can say yes to more than one bank even though he probably wouldn't open an account in two banks on the same day.